# Add rel="nofollow" and target="_blank" for external links permanently

Tags: wordpress

I would like to add rel="nofollow" and target="_blank" for all external links in my Wordpress posts and pages permanently. I am aware, that there are plugins, which do the same, but as soon as they get disabled, all changes will be reversed and the articles are the same as from the beginning.

I do not know how to differ between internal or external links nor how to check if there is already a rel="nofollow" or target="_blank" attribute.

I guess the best way of doing this would be using PHP instead of MySQL. I already searched the web for guides, tutorials or plugins, without success.

May someone help me? I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 6):

I have got a solution for applying nofollow to all existing and new external links. 
Copy the code into your functions.php of your activated theme

```
function add_nofollow_content($content) {
$content = preg_replace_callback('/]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i', function($m) {
    if (strpos($m[1], "YOUR_DOMAIN_ADDRESS") === false)
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    else
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    }, $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_nofollow_content');
```

You can also call the function `home_url()` instead of `"YOUR_DOMAIN_ADDRESS"` in the space provided to avoid hard coding of the domain name.

The code is tested and it works.
Hope this one helps.

Comment: Why does the else also have `target_blank` on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet:
http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/nofollow-external-links-only-the_content-and-the_excerpt/

> This great little snippet that will add rel=”nofollow” to external
>   links within both the_content and the_excerpt. Add this snippet to the
>   functions.php of your wordpress theme to enable nofollow external
>   links.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'my_nofollow');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_nofollow');
function my_nofollow($content) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/<a[^>]+/', 'my_nofollow_callback', $content);
}
function my_nofollow_callback($matches) {
    $link = $matches[0];
    $site_link = get_bloginfo('url');
    if (strpos($link, 'rel') === false) {
        $link = preg_replace("%(href=\S(?!$site_link))%i", 'rel="nofollow" $1', $link);
    } elseif (preg_match("%href=\S(?!$site_link)%i", $link)) {
        $link = preg_replace('/rel=\S(?!nofollow)\S*/i', 'rel="nofollow"', $link);
    }
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work okay, but I tend to code all of my internal links as `<a href="/parent/child-item/"`, which your code recognises as an external link. How can this apply to these relative URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding `rel"nofollow"` and `target="_blank"` to outgoing links *permanently* is more work than it can be shown here. You will have to rebuild the functions of plugins like [External Links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sem-external-links/) so that even links in your `wp_nav_menus` can be rewritten.

I have a suggestion that adds the desired attributes via JavaScript when the page is loaded. You can add this script directly to your theme header or you can keep it in a seperate file enqueing the script in your themes' `functions.php`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "a:not(a[href^='http://www.your-domain-name.com'],a[href^='javascript'],a[href^='#'])" ).attr({
                rel: "nofollow",
                target: "_blank"
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer of @rony-samuel and adjusted few things you might find useful.

Use the built-in `make_clickable` function to wrap links automatically. (E.g. useful when creating posts via API) - then check if the user has added additional classes to a link, (like a `button` to have a different styling) – we don't want to overwrite that, so just return the given markup with `$m[0]`.

Last thing is the regex. In combination with `make_clickable` it would output `<a <a href...` so a link in a link. I corrected the regex to avoid that.

```
// Auto warp links within content
add_filter( 'the_content', 'make_clickable' );

// Add target blank and nofollow to external links
// Do not overwrite links that probably have been placed manually in the content
// and contain classes like "button" or whatever etc. Since they were placed manually
// with additional styling, the editor can add target="_blank" manually as well if needed.

function external_links ($content) {
    $content = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<a[^>]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i',
    function($m) {
        $hasClass = (bool) preg_match('/class="[^"]*[^"]*"/', $m[0]);

        if (strpos($m[1], home_url()) === false && $hasClass === false)
            return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
        else
            return $m[0];
        },

        $content);
        return $content;
    }

// set a very low priority to ensure,
// all the content and shortcode things has been completed already
add_filter('the_content', 'external_links', 999);
```