# Add only to external links nofollow noopener and _blank tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to use the code which I have found on this thread 
[Add rel="nofollow" and target="_blank" for external links permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313634/add-rel-nofollow-and-target-blank-for-external-links-permanently)
The problem is that it is adding the nofollow, noopener and _blank tags to internal links as well. It should only be added to external links. What is wrong? Thanks

```
function add_nofollow_content($content) {
$content = preg_replace_callback('/]*href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i', function($m) {
    if (strpos($m[1], "https://example.com/") === false)
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    else
        return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[2].'</a>';
    }, $content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_nofollow_content');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function replaceAnchorsWithText($data) {

    $regex  = '/<a .* href=["|\']([^"|\']*)["|\'][^>]*>([^<]*)<\/a>/i';//regex
    if (is_array($data)) {
    if (strpos($data[1], "https://example.com/") === false)
        $data= '<a href="'.$data[1].'" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank">'.$data[2].'</a>';
  else
       $data='<a href="'.$data[1].'" target="_blank">'.$data[2].'</a>';

    }
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'replaceAnchorsWithText', $data);
}

$output = replaceAnchorsWithText('<a href="https://example.co">A</a>
Link Must Be In New line<a href="https://example.com/">B</a>');

echo $output;
```